# DBIx::Class / SQL::Abstract Apply SQL-Function to column in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbix-class

I just fiddled around with a complex SQL query generated with [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) (which under the hood uses [`SQL::Abstract`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract) for WHERE clauses).

I'm using the BETWEEN operator to filter entries:

```
# SELECT title FROM tracks WHERE begin BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-02'
$searchArgs->{'begin'} = { BETWEEN => ['2016-07-01', '2016-07-02' ] };
```

This will skip begin-dates actually ON the 2016-07-02. Probably because those begin-values are past midnight (00:00) of the 2016-07-02 and therefore not in the BETWEEN range (see example data on the end).

On the SQL-Side, this is easily fixed:

```
SELECT title FROM tracks WHERE DATE(begin) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-02'
# Note the DATE()-cast of begin
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `SQL::Abstract` syntax? I tried the column name as a scalar-ref (`$searchArgs->{\"DATE(begin)"}`) to get it passed by untouched, but it didn't work out.

Just using `$searchArgs->{'DATE(begin)'}` triggers an SQL-Error since there is no such column "DATE(begin)".

```
# Minimal example data
CREATE TABLE test ( title VARCHAR(255), begin timestamp );
INSERT INTO test (title, begin) VALUES ( 'Track 1', '2016-07-01T12:00:00'::timestamp), ( 'Track 2', '2016-07-02 12:00:00'::timestamp );
SELECT title FROM test WHERE begin BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-02';
SELECT title FROM test WHERE DATE(begin) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-02';
```

Comment: What does *"but it didn't work out"* mean?

Comment: I couldn't find a way, to get the DATE()-Function on the column-side.

Comment: Sure, but what happened when you tried?

Comment: I get an SQL-Engine error which complains about a non existing column name "SCALAR...". Because the Scalar-Ref as key in the Hash isn't evaluated in a special way, like the values are (Scalar refs mostly end up as plain SQL-Statements).

Comment: Okay, then you should add that information to your question. Is my answer below insufficient for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be that a date like `'2016-07-02'` is equivalent to `'2016-07-02T00:00:00'`, and `'2016-07-02T12:00:00'` is *greater than* that. Calling `DATE()` just truncates the time value so that the extra twelve hours are discarded

I suggest that you abandon `BETWEEN`, and use the equivalent `>=` and `<=` operators. You actually want all records up to but *not including* `'2016-07-03T0:00:00'` (that is, everything up to and including `2016-07-02T23:59:59` and any fractions of a second that your database may support) so you should write

```sql
SELECT title FROM test
WHERE begin BETWEEN >= '2016-07-01' AND begin < '2016-07-03';
```

or, in `DBIx::Class`

```perl
$searchArgs->{begin} = {
    '>=' => '2016-07-01',
    '<'  => '2016-07-03',
};
```

or if you have access only to the end date and want to avoid date arithmetic in your Perl code then just let the database do it for you

```
$searchArgs->{begin} = {
    '>=' => '2016-07-01',
    '<'  => \[ 'date(?) + 1', '2016-07-02' ],
};
```

---

If you insist on using a function instead of a simple table name in your WHERE comparison then it is possible by using literal SQL, but it's inadvisable as you will bypass all optimisation that the database can provide and it will have to resort to a linear search

The `DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook` documentation has this under [*Using SQL functions on the left hand side of a comparison*](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Using_SQL_functions_on_the_left_hand_side_of_a_comparison)

> Using SQL functions on the left hand side of a comparison is generally not a good idea since it requires a scan of the entire table. (Unless your RDBMS supports indexes on expressions - including return values of functions - and you create an index on the return value of the function in question.) However, it can be accomplished with `DBIx::Class` when necessary by resorting to literal SQL

Comment: Your solution implies some date math (2016-07-31 + 1 day => 2016-08-01). The realy query is executed dynamicly later. Beside that, it would work (but than also with BETWEEN). But probably it's not an DBIx::Class / SQL::Abstract problem anymore. With the mentioned limitation i have to resaerch further as it looks...

Comment: @ghandi: Okay then just use some explicit SQL to do the arithmetic. `'<'  => \[ 'date(?) + 1', '2016-07-02' ]` should work fine, although I haven't tested it. You really shouldn't just go silent if a solution doesn't quite fit, as then I have no way to know how to improve it

Comment: No worry, just wasn't online anymore. ;)
The `date(...) + 1` ist a good workaround. Thanks :)